# Detect Duplicates in Dataframe from all columns in R

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a dataset of pet names and colour listed next to owners as below;

```
Owner    Pet1_Name   Pet1_Colour    Pet2_Name   Pet2_Colour   Pet3_Name   Pet3_Colour
Barbie   Beary       Red            Brook       Yellow        Bridget     Pink
Cameron  Courtney    Green          Craig       Blue          Carrot      Black
Derek    Dingo       Green          Dracula     Purple        Drump       Brown
Barbie   Brady       Blue           Barnaby     Orange        Bank        White
Barbie   Brooke      Yellow         Bridget     Pink          Beary       Red
```

The last row is a duplicate of the first row but the pets are in a different order. One of the pet names is also slightly misspelt. I want to be able to identify that its a duplicate row.

I think I'll have to break the columns up separately and compare every possible pair but with large data, this will take a while.

I've tried `reclin`

```
p <- pair_blocking(df, df) %>% 
   filter_pairs_for_deduplication() %>%
   compare_pairs(by = c("Pet1_Name", "Pet1_Colour", "Pet2_Name", "Pet2_Colour", "Pet3_Name", "Pet3_Colour"), 
   default_comparator = jaro_winkler()) %>% 
   score_simsum() %>% 
   select_threshold(0.88)
```

but this isn't robust enough

Comment: `Brooke` and `Brook` are not the same,right? Maybe you need a fuzzy match?

Comment: Hi yes I'd want them to be considered the same :)